# Camel-Cdi not injecting CamelContext with Registery

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-cdi

I am using camel-cdi and it is injecting the CamelContext, detecting all the routes in project.
But I want a CamelContext with a registry because I have some components that I use  in camel routes like shown below.

```
    SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
    registry.put("actionProcessor", actionProcessor);
    registry.put("jpa", jpaComponent);
    registry.put("jtaTransactionManager", platformTransactionManager);

    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
```

When I inject CamelContext the components like actionProcess, jpa are not recognized. when in my Route I have

```
    .to("bean:actionProcessor?method=myMethod(${body})")
```

but my bean does not get executed.
I documentation I read use # before components name which are in registry but still it is not working.

Please suggest how can I achieve this using camel-cdi.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try with creating a `CdiCamelContext` (a subclass of DefaultCamelContext) ?

Otherwise, a more elegant would be to annotate your various classes, eg:

```
@Named("actionProcessor")
public class MyActionProcessor{
...
}
```

Comment: No, as per documentation camel-cdi gives an object of DefaultCamelContext. Other thing is I dont want to create an instance of CamelContext by my own. simply writing  @Inject CamelContext camelContext; I am able to get the instance of DefaultCamelContext and it is starting all the routes. only problem is it is not detecting the components that I have added in registry. I also tried creating a producer class which will return the object of SimpleRegistry. I also found that there is a class named org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelRegistry but I am not able to create an object of this class.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using this for years without any problem

```
public class ContextFactory {

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @ContextName("Demo")  
    static final CamelContext createContext() {
        CdiCamelContext context = new CdiCamelContext();                
        context.setStreamCaching(true);                
        context.disableJMX();       
        return context;
    }

}   


@ContextName("Demo")
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    from("...")
    .to("bean:actionProcessor?method=myMethod")
}


@Named("actionProcessor")
public class MyActionProcessor{

    public void myMethod(@Body String body) {}
}
```

Of course, in order to work, you need to activate the JEE bean discovery (=add a "beans.xml" file in META-INF or WEB-INF) !